# Prevent Unit Tests against Task<t>

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, nunit, resharper, fluent-assertions

I have the problem that some Unit Tests are written against async methods. These methods return `Task<t>` and I found one that tests if the return value is not null. Instead the test should have tested if the return value of the task is not null. This is also a problem when changing a method from sync returning t to async returning `Task<t>`. Are there any ways to show a warning when a Unit Test tests against Task? I'm using **NUnit**, **FluentAssertions** and **ReSharper**. Preferred would of course be something that resides within the code base and can be shared with the rest of the team (like ReSharper settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with ReSharper Custom Patterns.

```
$task$.Should()
```

with `task` being an Expression placeholder with Expression Type = `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`. Then I set the severity to Warning.